# Is it possible to configure tab completion with PowerTab for aliased functions?

Tags: powershell, command-line, powershell-2.0, powertab

I have written a set of PowerShell helper functions for the Micrsosoft TFS and Micrsosoft  TFPT command line tools (some which in turn use the Posh cmdlets included with TFPT).  To shorten the commands from their standard naming conventions, like `Get-TfsStatus` and `Invoke-TfsCommit`, I created aliases as well (e.g. `tf-status` and `tf-commit`).  I use PowerTab as well for tab completion, but v0.99.6 does not support tab completion with aliases by default.

How do you configure tab completion so that my aliases, which all start with `tf-` can show me the list of available commands?

I see that PowerTab includes an editor for modifying tab expansion behavior, but it is not clear to me exactly what I would need to configure.  I also know with PowerTab turned off, the default posh tab completion works with aliases.

Example function and alias:

```
function Get-TfsStatus([switch]$all) {
    # Do something
}

Set-Alias tf-status Get-TfsStatus
Set-Alias tf-st Get-TfsStatus
```

Note: Originally, I had the actual function names as `tf-status`, `tf-commit`, etc., but when you `Import-Module`, PowerShell complains that I was not following the naming standards for PowerShell functions.

Comment: @JasonMArcher We need you help here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a use case I had anticipated, so it is not well supported.  However, there is an easy way to hack this in so long as your aliases continue to have a "-" in their name.

Edit **line 957** of **TabExpansionCore.ps1** to add "Alias" to the list of command types.

```
Get-Command -CommandType Alias,Function,ExternalScript,Filter,Cmdlet -Name "$($Matches[1])*" |
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  Note that I changed it on line 1056 in the latest from CodePlex as I'm running Posh v3 and needed the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you *can* use non-standard names for your functions without getting warnings.

```
Import-Module <<path_to_your_module>> -DisableNameChecking
```

Although, from experience, it is a good habit to follow (in most cases) the naming convention.

By default, autocomplete does *not* work on aliases.  What does work, even for aliases, is parameter completion.  So whether you type `tf-status -a` or `Get-TfsStatus -a`, if you press Tab, it will autocomplete to `-All`.

Neither the Powershell console nor the ISE editor have an option to enable alias completion.

For your case, I would suggest to use the "wrong" name (no alias), import with `-DisableNameChecking` and the autocomplete will then work for `tf-status`.

Concerning PowerTab -- this is not fully supported in all hosts.  Check [this page](http://powertab.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Host%20Support&referringTitle=Documentation) to see which functionality is supported where.  I don't know it well - I'm sure it's possible to add aliases, but it might be a tedious task and would need to be done for each user.  If someone doesn't have powertab, they won't be able to use autocompletion for the aliases you define in your module.

Comment: I should have mentioned it, but I am aware of `-DisableNameChecking`.  I'm of the camp, though, that believes the naming standards are there for a reason.  The standard Posh console does in fact auto-complete aliases.  I tested it by typing `tf-[TAB]`.  It completes to the first one, which is wrong, but it does do it.  So, if more of the command is typed, it gets closer to choosing the correct one.  Lastly, I am not concerned about other devs.  We have PowerTab under version control and we all use the same config.